# How can I replace the no break space (nbsp) with a normal space?

Tags: java, ascii

I see that in many examples it is simply this:

```
message.replaceAll(nbsp, " ");
```

Of course it is saying local variable nbsp not found though. How can I simply replace any nbsp in a string with the normal space?

Comment: Look at the rest of the example.

Answer (score 11):

You need to create a local variable `String nbsp = "&nbsp;"`

or simple use `message.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");`

This will also work:

```
message.replaceAll("\u00a0"," ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String message = "a&nbsp;b&nbsp;c";
String nbsp = "&nbsp;";
message = message.replaceAll(nbsp, " ");
System.out.println(message);
```

Output: "a b c"